# Excel File not generating in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I m trying to Scrap bunch of url .Output is right excel file not generating to store all the scrape data

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    driver.get(f"{df.loc[i, 'URL']}")
    f_name = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[@href]")
    for elem in f_name:
        urls =  print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
df.loc[i,urls]
print({i})
df.to_excel('Results.xlsx', index=False)
time.sleep(2)
```

Python is not generating any excel files

Comment: interpreter reaching that line? Try adding some dummy `print` statement before & after that `df.to_excel` ...lIke `print('python executed above line')`

Comment: yup did that too . Not generating any excel file

Answer (score -1):

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

workbook.close()